# Redirecting within `$routeProvider`

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

This is how my `routeProvider` setup looks like, using `$scope.$digest` or `$scope.$apply` :

```
$routeProvider.when('/events', {
    templateUrl: 'event-list/event-list.html',
    controller: 'eventListCtrl'
});
$routeProvider.when('/event/:eventCode', {
    templateUrl: 'event/event.html',
    controller: 'eventCtrl'
});
$routeProvider.when('/event/:eventCode/attendees', {
    templateUrl: 'event/attendees/attendees.html',
    controller: 'eventAttendeesCtrl'
});
$routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: ' ',
    controller: ['$scope','$location', function($scope,$location) {
        $location.path('events');
        $location.replace();
        $scope.$digest(); // important - digest the changes in rootScope
    }]
});
$routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/404'});
```

**EDIT** I also have a base i.e `<base href="/">` which will change to `<base href="/dashboard/">` in production.

Via this code my `root` or **/** will be redirected to **/events**

I want **/event/:eventCode** to be redirected to **/event/:eventCode/attendees** but if I write a similar code to what I wrote for root

It says **$digest already in progress** when I hit **/event/:eventCode**.

Comment: could you please provide the eventCtrl code

Comment: @shushanthp actually I will to delete `event/event.html` and related js which have `eventCtrl`, this is just a placeholder page till I'm able to redirect it to **/event/:eventCode/attendees**

Answer (score 0):

Found out that there's a simple `redirectTo` of doing this (I have also changed URL pattern for no confusions between actual folder and link):

```
$routeProvider.when('/events', {
    templateUrl: 'event-list/event-list.html',
    controller: 'eventListCtrl'
});
$routeProvider.when('/e/:eventCode', {
    redirectTo: '/e/:eventCode/attendees'
});
$routeProvider.when('/e/:eventCode/attendees', {
    templateUrl: 'event/attendees/attendees.html',
    controller: 'eventAttendeesCtrl'
});
$routeProvider.when('/', {
    redirectTo: '/events'
});
$routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/events'});
```